# Is it possible to map Alt + Arrow Key to the start and end of a line in various applications?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keymap

I really miss the ability to use the arrow keys and a modifier to move between the start and the end of a line from OSX. Coming from OSX and doing this, it's a real hassle to have to move over to the other side of the keyboard to hit the home and end keys.

Is Alt combined with the arrows keys used for something else that might bite me later?

Comment: The arrows and the home, end, etc are in the same place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Autohotkey and following script:

`!Left::Send, {Home}
!Right::Send, {End}
!+Left::Send, {Shift down}{Home}{Shift up}
!+Right::Send, {Shift down}{End}{Shift up}`

Last two lines make work selection like home\end + shift!

Comment: Thank you! This works nicely.

In case somebody need that in AHK V2: https://gist.github.com/ColCh/a88428c4d59318a36030edbf44810612