# Is it possible to remap key combinations in windows without AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to remap alt+arrows to work like home, end, etc like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/895001/is-it-possible-to-map-alt-arrow-key-to-the-start-and-end-of-a-line-in-various) but I prefer to not have another program running in the background.

Is it possible to do this without AutoHotKey? Is there anything like [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) that can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without a 3rd party program running in the background.  Sharpkeys can switch a *single* keypress with another, via a registry hack.  It cannot do multiple keypresses.  Since you want to press *multiple* keys at once, you *must* have a program like AHK intercept the keystrokes and programmatically determine what to do.

AHK is extremely small and lightweight.  It isnt going to slow your system down.